# Push view controller from a Child View controller

Tags: ios, swift

From a button action, I have presented a **viewController**, from that presented **VC**, add another button and on that button action added a **childView** like this -

```
let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Profile", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "APPopUpViewControllerViewController") as! APPopUpViewControllerViewController
self.addChild(vc)
vc.view.frame = self.view.frame
self.view.addSubview(vc.view)
vc.didMove(toParent: self)
```

All are working perfectly till now, but when i try to push a **viewController** from this child VC , it does not work. How can i push a **viewController** from a **childView** ??

Push viewController code -

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "WPLogin", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WPSigninViewController") as! WPSigninViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
print(parent)
print(parent?.navigationController)   
self.parent?.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: Instead of self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true) , i tried your code but no luck @Sh_Khan

Comment: Getting 1st print - Optional(<AmiProbashi.APProfileViewController: 0x7fe980cb82c0>) 2nd print - nil @Sh_Khan

Comment: this means you dont embed `APProfileViewController` inside a navigation control , go add it in storyboard/code , `pushViewController` won't work without it

Comment: A navigation Controller has already embedded in profile VC, but still not working. I have made this child view from a presented VC, is that the problem?

Comment: no the add child must be from a vc that's pushed not presented

Comment: Then I have to make the first vc pushed rather than make it presented to make it work. Thanks for your help. @SH_Khan

Comment: Correct. The parent of the `Profile` VC has to be pushed onto a navigation controller in order to be managed by a navigation controller.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `self.navigationController` is nil, so your optional chaining is failing.

Comment: Adding to that, if you are lazy like me just change the `?` to `!` to force a crash to see what is exactly nil and then start to look into it from there

Answer (score 0):

How do you present your **ViewController** ? If You have pushed it to a navigation controller, then your code is perfect and it should work I think.

If not, then try to present the **WPSigninViewController** modally as

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "WPLogin", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WPSigninViewController") as! WPSigninViewController
self.present(vc, animated: true)
```

and It should work.

If **ViewController** is your rootController, you can add a NavigationController to it :

```
let viewController = ViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```